# MIME Type issue for datetime picker

Tags: javascript, css, iis, mime-types

I am getting the below error, however the js file is accessible

Refused to apply style from 'bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' because its MIME type ('application/javascript') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

It was working fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to include the JavaScript file "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" as a stylesheet in your HTML. This error message lets you know that it won't accept javascript files, it will only accept stylesheet (eg CSS ) files.

If you mistakenly included the "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" file as a link to your stylesheet, you should remove it and include the correct CSS file.

If not like this, please provide enough code or a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bootstrap-datepicker I hope it's helpful for you. first add cdn links in your header and then use html and then js and you can change its style.

> cdn link

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

> html

```
 <div class="form-group" layout="row" style="margin-top:4px;">
        <span style="margin-top:7px" flex="20">Date</span>
        <input placeholder="dd MM yyyy" style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;margin-top: 5px; border-radius: 7px; width: 50%; height: 36px;" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="datepicker"  ng-model="date">
    </div>
```

> js

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd MM yyyy', // Date format
        autoclose: true, 
        todayHighlight: true // Highlight today's date
    });
```

I hope you like it.

Comment: this is working first add cdn links then html and js. that is a example user can change it's style or anything he want.